# libgdx ios app getting rejected for not working on IPv6 network using Ec2 and Kryonet

Tags: ios, amazon-ec2, libgdx, robovm, kryonet

My App has now gotten rejected twice for not working on an IPv6 network on a device running IOS 10.2 My App was built using these resources and I was hoping someone could give me some insight on where to start looking.

Server:

- Amazon EC2 t2.micro
- IP address is IPv4 however the server says IPv6 is enabled
- All traffic is allowed in security groups
- Windows Server 2016

Libraries:

- LibGDX 1.9.5
- Kryo 2.23.1-SNAPSHOT
- Kryonet 2.18
- MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork 2.3.0

Please let me know which of these is most likely the culprit so I can proceed to fix it thank you!

Comment: I ran into the same problem for my libGDX app. I thought it was ipv6 related, because Apple told me so. It was not, and I solved the problems using the Application Loader, which canceled the upload process and showed the error.

Comment: Did you use robovm? I always upload using the application loader

Comment: No, I'm using the Multi-OS Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this fixed. I was originally connecting to my servers by the IP address and have now switched it to the DNS. Works fine and made it through app review!